# Is it possible to get the commit order inside MySql?

Tags: mysql

I need to *incrementally* copy all changes from a table to another table. The idea is to have a "materialized view" like this:

1. First we create the materialized view:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_materialized_view (PRIMARY KEY (table_one_pk, table_two_pk)) AS
SELECT t1.pk AS table_one_pk,
       t2.pk AS table_two_pk,
       t1.last_update AS table_one_last_update,
       t2.last_update AS table_two_last_update
       /*, other columns */
FROM table_one AS t1
JOIN table_two AS t2 ...
```

Important:

- `t1.pk` and `t2.pk` are the primary keys of `table_one` and `table_two`. Together they form the composite primary key of the materialized view. This is important to the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` command shown bellow to work.
- `t1.last_update` and `t2.last_update` are `DATETIME` columns that are always updated with `NOW()` by the application, whenever a record is inserted or updated in `table_one` or `table_two`. I use these columns to know what records must be inserted or updated in the materialized view since the last time I did this.

2. To capture the changes incrementally, create an event and schedule a stored procedure with this code to run periodically:

```sql
DECLARE mv_last_update DATETIME;

-- Get the last time we synchronize the MV
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(table_one_last_update), MAX(table_two_last_update))
INTO mv_last_update
FROM my_materialized_view;

INSERT INTO my_materialized_view
SELECT /* all columns from my_materialized_view */
FROM table_one AS t1
JOIN table_two AS t2 ...
WHERE t1.last_update > mv_last_update
   OR t2.last_update > mv_last_update
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    /* all columns from my_materialized_view except the ones that form the primary key */
```

This will capture all inserts and updates made to `table_one` and `table_two` since the last time we call the procedure and pass them to the materialized view. Note: this do not capture deletes, but it's not a problem for me because my app doesn't delete records physically.

The problem with this code is that we use a `DATETIME` column to versioning the changes and the *order that transactions commit may be different than the order of which `last_update = NOW()` were executed*. For instance suppose we have two transactions changing `table_one` in parallel:

1. At `2022-09-20 10:30:00` transaction A starts and inserts one record and sets it's `last_update` column to `'2022-09-20 10:30:00'`.
2. At `2022-09-20 10:31:00` transaction B starts and inserts one record and sets it's `last_update` column to `'2022-09-20 10:31:00'`.
3. At `2022-09-20 10:32:00` transaction B commits.
4. At `2022-09-20 10:33:00` the stored procedure is called and the materialized view is updated.
5. At `2022-09-20 10:34:00` transaction A commits.
6. At `2022-09-20 10:35:00` the stored procedure is called and the materialized view is updated again.

With these sequence of events the data inserted by transaction A would never be copied to the materialized view, because:

- The first time the procedure was called (item 4), transaction A have not been committed yet.
- The second time the procedure was called (item 6) the where condition `t1.last_update > mv_last_update` would not capture the change, since `mv_last_update` would be `'2022-09-20 10:31:00'` (inserted into the MV by transaction B) and transaction A's `last_update` was `'2022-09-20 10:30:00'`.

What I need is a better way to sequence the changes made to a table, so when the procedure runs it could safely get every change that was made since the last time it was executed. This sequence, or versioning, should follow the same order commands are recorded in the binlog or, to say it in a different way, the same order transactions were committed.

Is it possible to do so in MySql? I'm using version 8.0.23.

Comment: It sounds like you need a mechanism to lock for changes, so only one transaction can run at a time.  Like [this](https://medium.com/@ibraheemabukaff/locking-rows-in-mysql-e84fd3bbb8cd#) ?